# Sign multiple pdf with itextsharp and token prompts for pin every time

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, smartcard, pkcs#11

Hi I am trying to prevent multiple pin prompts for every pdf that needs to be signed.

I am using code from this [example](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/chapter3/C3_11_SignWithToken/C3_11_SignWithToken.cs) :

Pin is required when this part of code get process :

```
MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize,
subfilter);
```

Is there any way to memorize token pin and sing rest of pdfs without prompting for pin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found solution, this code does the trick :

```
...
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)pk.PrivateKey;

CspParameters cspp = new CspParameters();
cspp.KeyContainerName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
cspp.ProviderName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
// cspp.ProviderName = "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider";

cspp.ProviderType = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;

cspp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt;

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp);

rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
...
MakeSignature.SignDetached(...);
```

Creating `CspParameters` before signing, remebers the pin code. There is official documentacion on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) .

Comment: You may also want to fill in `cspp.KeyPassword` field for the password.
I am experiencing a similar problem except that the PIN is asked when I try to sign 2nd, 3rd, 4th... nth document. For the first signing I don't get any prompts, while they start from the 2nd, until I restart the app so that I could sign without prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: There must be something wrong with that because I can sign multiple docs with single prompt.

Comment: It seems *SafeNet CSP* was not installed right. What I needed to do is add a registry key `NonRepudiationOID` with empty value in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\General]`. Now it works fine.