# Sign multiple pdfs with iText7 without inputting Smart Card Pin multiple times

Tags: pdf, rsa, digital-signature, itext7, smartcard

I'm attempting to sign multiple seperate PDFs with iText7. I'm able to do so, but it asks for my smart card pin for every file that it signs. I wish for it to only need the pin once, and then sign all the files.

I tried implenting the solution from this question ([Sign multiple pdf with itextsharp and token prompts for pin every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523779/sign-multiple-pdf-with-itextsharp-and-token-prompts-for-pin-every-time)), but it still asks for my smart card pin for every pdf file.
This is my current code:

```
using namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
using namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs
using namespace Org.BouncyCastle.X509
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography
using namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1
using namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Math
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.DSACertificateExtensions
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.ECDsaCertificateExtensions
using namespace iText.Signatures
using namespace iText.Signatures.IExternalSignature
using namespace iText.Signatures.PdfSigner
using namespace iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.CryptoStandard
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf

Import-Module "C:\Users\Dactal Sharp\Desktop\itext7module.1.0.34\IText7Module.psd1"

$cert =  Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object{$_.Extensions.EnhancedKeyUsages.FriendlyName -contains "Document Signing"}
$cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($cert)
$openFlags = [OpenFlags]::ReadWrite , [OpenFlags]::OpenExistingOnly
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store($cert)
$storeName = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store($storeName, $store.Location) 
$store.Open($openFlags)
$store.Certificates
$bccert = [Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities]::FromX509Certificate($cert)

[Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[]]$chain = $bccert

$stampingProperties = [StampingProperties]::new()

$rsaObj = $cert.PrivateKey

$cspp = [CspParameters]::new()

$cspp.KeyContainerName = $rsaObj.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName

$cspp.CryptoKeySecurity = $rsaObj.CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity

$cspp.KeyNumber =$rsaObj.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber

$cspp.ProviderName = $rsaObj.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName

$cspp.ProviderType = $rsaObj.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType

$cspp.KeyPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter Smart Card PIN" -AsSecureString

$cspp.Flags = [CspProviderFlags]::UseExistingKey

$rsa = [RsaCryptoServiceProvider]::new($cspp)

$rsaObj.PersistKeyInCsp = $true

$rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = $true

[IExternalSignature]$signature = [AsymmetricAlgorithmSignature]::new($rsa, [DigestAlgorithms]::SHA256)

$digest = [DigestAlgorithms]::SHA256

#[IExternalSignature]$signature = [X509Certificate2Signature]::new($cert, "SHA256")

$signature

$chain.Count

$i = 0

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Dactal Sharp\Downloads\input test" | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -match "testunsig*"}){

$pdfReader = [PdfReader]::new($file.FullName)

$stream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new("C:\Users\Dactal Sharp\Downloads\test\test" + [string]$i + ".pdf",2)

$i++

$pdfSigner = [PdfSigner]::new($pdfReader,$stream,$stampingProperties.UseAppendMode())

[PdfSignatureAppearance]$appearance = $pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance()

$appearance.SetRenderingMode([PdfSignatureAppearance+RenderingMode]::NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION)

$appearance.SetCertificate($bccert)

$appearance.setReasonCaption($null)

$appearance.SetLocationCaption($null)

$appearance.setReuseAppearance($true)

$pdfSigner.SetFieldName("Signature2")

$pdfSigner.SignDetached($signature,$bccert,$null,$null,$null,0,[iText.Signatures.PdfSigner+CryptoStandard]::CMS)

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your smartcard and your smart card reader _allow_ multiple signatures with a single PIN input? Some smart cards explicitly require the PIN anew for each signing call, and some smart card readers don't support programmatically PIN input.

Comment: That's something I didn't consider. How would I go about checking that?

Comment: This first thing to clarify, what the signature is supposed to represent. As soon as it implies, that somewhat read and agreed with the content, the proposed PIN caching is impossible. There may also exist further legal obstacles.

Comment: @JDactal *"That's something I didn't consider. How would I go about checking that?"* - Well, if you have a technical documentation of card and reader, you may find it there. Otherwise consider asking the person/shop from whom you got your card and reader.